# Formatting results to display two decimal places

Tags: python, number-formatting

I'm trying to format the follow program so that the results for 'average' are only displayed to 2 decimal places. I get that the `'%.2f' %` code is used to do that, but I can't figure out how to integrate it into the final line of code producing an error.

Here is the program and I'm working on.

```
#the user has to enter three numbers for the program to average

#request the first number
answer1 = input('Please enter the first number: ')
answer1 = int(answer1)

#request the second number
answer2 = input('Please enter the second number: ')
answer2 = int(answer2)

#request the third number
answer3 = input('Please enter the third number: ')
answer3 = int(answer3)

final = answer1 + answer2 + answer3
final = int(final)

#print the average
print('The average of these numbers is ', final / 3)
```

It's the final line here that I can't figure out where to insert the `'%.2f' %` to return the results for 2 decimal places.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 0):

```
print('The average of these numbers is %0.2f' %final / 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the variable `final` into `float`. For example, final as an integer would result in `10 / 3 = 3`, but as a float `10.0 / 3 = 3.333333`.
Then you can use the function `round()` to round float to certain number of decimals.
Example:

```
a = 10.0
final = round(a/3, 2)
final is now 3.33
```